# PHP, doing form checks with UTF8

Tags: php, forms, utf-8

So to support multilanguage on the site I need to make sure all data going into the database is stored as utf8. My question is, is there a class out there that does form checks and data sanitization for forms using utf8 formatted form data? Right now I do checks such as if empty, or if the form data is a certain length, but would have to use different commands because of utf8. So just wanted to check and see if there is a pre-existing class for this type of checking/sanitizing as I try not to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Any type of UTF-8 data is accepted? User should enter musical notations for example? Or math formulas? Please specify what you would like to check, UTF-8 contains a lot of diverse things.

Comment: @hakre well its form data that should accept things for events/stories/listings etc in multiple languages.

Comment: Well data and things, that's sort of really concrete. I wonder if you know about the [`mb_` function family](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php).

Comment: @hakre Yes I do know about the mb functions. I was just wondering if there was a class out there that did all the work. I see a ton of classes out there that are for form validation but not for utf8 data.

Comment: Probably you should link existing classes that do that for other data in your question so it's more clear what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some general information about the topic can be found in *Building Scalable Web Sites* by Cal Hernderson (O'Reilly 2006) in chapter 5 ([Chapter 5 as PDF](http://oreilly.com/catalog/web2apps/chapter/ch05.pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is there a class out there that does form checks and data sanitization for forms using utf8 formatted form data?

This shouldn't be necessary in the first place. If your form (and everything else along the way) is properly encoded as UTF-8, there should be no hiccups.

If everything is properly set up, only thing where things can go wrong is when the user enters invalid characters into the form. It's impossible to reliably defend against that - but the risk of this happening is minimal.

If you have a real-world situation where invalid characters can make it into the data, you can do an [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/function.iconv) with the `//IGNORE` option to weed out invalid characters:

```
$data = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $data);
```

the same way, you can find out whether a string contains invalid characters by comparing string lengths before and after the iconv().

Comment: Emphasis on that there *should* be no hiccups. You should check for valid UTF-8 data.

Comment: Im not really looking to validate if the data is utf8 but rather validate with rules such as field cant be empty, field cant be more than 200 characters long etc. Basically form validation with php and utf8 data. Thought there might be a pre-existing script/class out there that did that instead of creating it from scratch.